# Handlebars not rendering template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have been on this issue for more than a couple of hours now and I have no idea why it isn't working. It's a simple {{#each}} block. I will add I am new to Handlebars.js.

I thought maybe there was something wrong with my [vanilla] javascript so I translated the code to JQuery, but that did not help.

**My Template:**

```
<div class="eventListContainer" id="handlebarsEntryPoint">
</div>

<script id="eventList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each event}}
    <div class="evenEvent eventContent">
        <div class="eventThumbnails leftContent">
            EX1: {{this.city_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="eventInformation middleContent">
            EX2: {{this.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="eventGoogleMap rightContent">
            EX3: {{this.owner}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

***Note***: If I replace {{#each event}} with {{#each this}} then my template (as in only the HTML) is displayed without any data.

**My Javascript:**

```
eventList = response.events;
console.log(eventList);

var source = document.getElementById('eventList-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var compiledHTML = template(eventList);
// compiledHTML = template({event: ['56','789','91011']});
var entryPoint = document.getElementById('handlebarsEntryPoint');
entryPoint.innerHTML = compiledHTML;
```

- I tried removing the "this" keyword from {{this.city_name}} but that didn't do anything.
- I tried a simpler example to just get the array working (the line that is commented out under My Javascript) but that also wasn't working.
- I have tripled checked to see if maybe I had incorrect logic to insert HTML.
- I have looked at countless examples which I tried modeling but still nothing.

**console.log(eventList) gives me:**

```
Object {event: Array[5]}
  event: Array[5]
    0: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
  __proto__: Object
```

I am not looking for a solution in JQuery. Thanks in advance :D

**Edit 1 - Contents of an Object in the event Array**

```
https://sdjs.slack.com/files/jacome09/F2BNNPDRN/events_object.js
```

Comment: Have you tried "event.something" instead of "this.something" ?

Comment: @aethyn No I have not. I just tried it now but it didn't do anything

Comment: Can you post the content of the objects in the array?

Comment: @JustH the link I provided in the edit is a similar object as the one in my post. one difference though, is that the object in the link is the entire response I get from the server.

Comment: I only have experience with MustacheJS, but for those, the inner data is just accessed via the `.`, e.g. `{{.city_name}}`

Comment: @Steve - gave me a server error :(

Comment: The syntax might be quite different. For example, in Mustache, the foreach loop syntax is `{{#event}}TEMPLATE{{/event}}`. Sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```js
var source = document.getElementById('eventList-template').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var compiledHTML = template({event: [{city_name: 'KC',id:'56',owner:'MO'},{city_name: 'SF',id:'1000',owner:'CA'}]});
var entryPoint = document.getElementById('handlebarsEntryPoint');
entryPoint.innerHTML = compiledHTML;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div class="eventListContainer" id="handlebarsEntryPoint">
</div>

<script id="eventList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each event as |ev|}}
    <div class="evenEvent eventContent">
        <div class="eventThumbnails leftContent">
            EX1: {{ev.city_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="eventInformation middleContent">
            EX2: {{ev.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="eventGoogleMap rightContent">
            EX3: {{ev.owner}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up moving my client-side Handlebars to only server-side. Honestly I don't know why I was using both. But, I just got it working a minute ago. I was still having issues about serving a precompiled template to client-side. Should anyone read this I would be more than happy to explain. In a nutshell, I ported this code to my server. @Steve - thank you, though, for the input!

Comment: Since the code above does solve the problem as defined in the question, you might consider marking this as correct.

Comment: I think I misinformed you. I wrote, "I ported **this** code," but I was referring to my original code's post. I never tested your code. Also, I was able to get a different working example through the browser at [tryhandlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/), and even that code wasn't working in my application. So truthfully, I still don't know what the problem was.